# Update object property with checkbox with boolean value. render is one step late

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `Main` component

```
const Main = () => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({
    property1: false,
  });

  return <Comp obj={obj} setObj={setObj} />;
};

export default Main;
```

and I have component

```
const Comp = ({ obj, setObj }) => {
  const HandleProperty1 = (e) => {
    setObj({ ...obj, property1: !obj.property1 });
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="property1"
      checked={obj.property1}
      onChange={() => HandleProperty1()}
    />
  );
};

export default Comp;
```

when I try to check `checkbox` it updates the `obj` property but does not render that checkbox is updated and it's stuck as unchecked.

Comment: React components [must be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), `comp` ---> `Comp` and `main` ---> `Main`

Comment: @NickParsons yes i know. i just write it directly here for example

Comment: It's great that you've created an example, but unfortunately, it doesn't reproduce your problem. Running your code updates the checkbox in the UI as expected. You can [edit] your question to create a [mre] using [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support) to help show the issue

Comment: You might be having issues with a closure using an old `obj` state value. You can check if that's the case by seeing if `setObj(obj => ({ ...obj, property1: !obj.property1 }))` resolves your issue.

Comment: @NickParsons still not works. i tried to use onClick instead of onChange and now state updates on every click but checkbox is always unchecked.

also i'm trying to set up code snippet rn.

Comment: dude check the name of the propery and name of the input, it could be different

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74589233/1432422

Answer (score 0):

i had my checkbox inside this div with data-toggle="buttons"

```
<div data-toggle="buttons"></div>
```

which is from bootstrap. it caused not to check my checkboxes. i was going crazy.